# Using OCaml to write text to a clipboard

Tags: ocaml

I am currently working on a terminal-based text editor in OCaml. I am trying to figure out how to write some selected text to the system's clipboard, so that one could copy text out of the text editor, and paste it elsewhere.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to help unless you specify the system you're using.

One way that would work on the systems I'm familiar with would be to use a command-line program to load the clipboard. In macOS you can run `echo string | pbcopy` as a command, for example.

This is, of course, much less efficient that using a system library. In the big picture this might not matter.

If you want to use a system library, you will most likely have to write an interface using the OCaml FFI or ctypes. If you specify your system, somebody will probably be able to tell you the function you need to call.